# Python - Can't run code during while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am pretty new to python, and while using a module to print out packets being received I can't execute code while the while loop that reads the packets is being executed. Here is a basic example. Any help would be appreciated.

```
def foo():
    while True:
        print("bar")

foo()
print("foobar")
```

i want it to print foobar once after the while loop has stared, is this possible?

Comment: Flow control is a fundamental concept in computing. If you want these events not to block each other, you'll need to use multiple processes or threads, and you [almost certainly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) are solving the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: I think the downvotes are because this question demonstrates a basic lack of knowledge about the way computers process instructions, and the downvoter(s) do(es)n't feel that answers to such a question are appropriate. That sometimes happens.

Answer (score 0):

The program executes sequentially, so the `print` will never happen because of the infinite loop. So you must use a thread to circumvent  this issue, allowing you to simultaneously execute code like so:

```
threading.Thread(target = foo).start() # new thread instead of foo() in the main thread
```

Comment: I don't why there is a downvote too. Threads are the way to go.

Comment: This is _a_ solution, but I strongly suspect that it solves [problem Y](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (not the downvoter).

Comment: Recommending threads to an obvious newbie who has trouble understanding simple non-threaded code, without understanding the actual domain-level problem, is not good advice. The fact that this looks like a simple one-line solution only makes things worse.

Answer (score 0):

Typically in Python (and most other languages), you start with just one thread of execution.

A `while True: ...` is an infinite loop – unless code inside the loop breaks out, or something external interrupts it, it never ends. So your code never reaches the call to `print('foobar')` line.

You could put a special case inside the `while` loop, for the first pass through, that reports what you want. Or you could look into using multiple threads of execution – an advanced topic.

Comment: Best answer so far, I am withdrawing mine. Just one additional note: be aware that multi-threaded programs are often hard to maintain and debug, and you should avoid them if possible. It is often (but not always) better to redesign your program than to use multiple threads.